# Fitting a navbar inside a column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, navbar

Bear with me here:

I have a row with three columns 2-8-2 in which I want to put the navbar in the center column fixed at the top of the page. The content for the page needs to match the width of the navbar which is why I was trying to attempt this.

Make sense?

Here is the code as requested that doesn't work. Figured it would just be simpler to describe a basic set up but...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/site-design.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body style="padding-top: 70px">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="width:20%"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container-fluid ">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/NYH Banner.jpg" width="210" height="44" alt=""/></a></div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Understand Hypnotherapy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services
                          <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Online Hypnotherapy</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Learn Hypnotherapy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Self Hypnosis</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>        
                        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Locate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>


                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
              <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="width:20%"></div>
    </div>
</div>







    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.navbar
        {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav 
        {
            line-height: 54px;
            height: 54px;
            padding-top: 0;
            background-color:transparent;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to fit a 210px image and all those links inside of 8 columns; even with a standard navbar your navigation links are pushed below the navbar on viewport change. What is the actual content width the nav edges need to match?

Comment: That's what I though but the client is... Being difficult about things. His original site was built in iWeb about 6 years ago and he is all about everything being laid out exactly. Am currently schooling him on responsive design and fluid layout. Thankfully he's a good friend so I can not so politely inform him of his... inflexibility of thought. Polite way to put it.  Lol